# Usage of "imperative to [verb]ing"

Tags: verbs, word-usage

From what I learned, we could use *imperative to [verb]ing*, but when I read my book, I see this sentence:

> An accurate analysis of surveys is **imperative to building** a good understanding of customer needs.

Why do we use *building* here?

Please help :)

Comment: It is imperative to [the process of] building a good understanding.

Comment: Whoever has edited this question, correcting the grammar, has made it a non-question.

Answer (score 1):

A brief look in via the google-books, finds that "imperative" (meaning a requirement) appears in two locutions.  The first is "*X* is imperative"+verb form.  This is your example.  From *[Physical Abusers and Sexual Offenders: Forensic and Clinical Strategies](https://books.google.com/books?id=xH9ucrMFdC8C&pg=PA119&dq=%22is%20imperative%20to%20understanding%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBWoVChMIo53RkLKCyAIVwXU-Ch3_aApK#v=onepage&q=%22is%20imperative%20to%20understanding%22&f=false)* by S. A. Johnson

> ... I believe that *reading the following authors' works* is
>   **imperative** to understanding the sexual offender....

The "to" here means "for [the purpose of]", and it would be just as acceptable to say "for understanding." However, the infinitive: "reading is imperative to understand" is much more common.

The second locution is "the imperative is"+verb form.  From *[Becoming Canonical in American Poetry](https://books.google.com/books?id=GZBQ1D-CF0gC&pg=PA11&dq=%22imperative%20is%20to%20understand%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIu_PniLmCyAIVi1o-Ch1IVwRO#v=onepage&q=%22imperative%20is%20to%20understand%22&f=false)* by T. Morris:

> If in imagining the future we are constrained by our past, one
>   **imperative is** to understand that past ....

In this case when the complement is a verb form, it's the infinitive.  I was unable to find a gerund to take that role.

Comment: In these usages, _imperative_ seems to me like the second cousin of the right word, as Mark Twain put it when he raked Cooper over the coals. The right word is probably _essential_ here. They're both Latin and formal and mean more or less the same thing, but _imperative_ is deontic and involves ordering and obeying -- and makes one wonder who's ordering whom to do what -- whereas _essential_ is epistemic and involves only observation, understanding, and logical conclusion.

Comment: I think "imperative" here is used to give weight to an argument from authority.  But an uptick on your comment for mentioning the "The Literary Offenses of James Fenimore Cooper," possibly the funniest thing ever written in the English language.